# F# Use base type of discriminated union

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

I'm learning F# and struggling trying to use discriminated unions. I have a simple case where I'm trying to use `Map.map` on a simple discriminated union of the type Map but its saying there is a type mismatch. I'm basically just trying to use the type Prices as a Map

Here is a simplified example:

```
type Prices = Prices of Map<string, int>

let GetSalePrice (prices: Prices) = prices |> Map.map (fun k v -> (k, v * 2))
```

Gives me this error:

```
/Users/luke/code/chronos/Chronos.Mining/Chronos.Mining.Actors/Untitled-1(22,47): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    'Prices -> 'a'    
but given a
    'Map<'b,'c> -> Map<'b,'d>'    
The type 'Prices' does not match the type 'Map<'a,'b>'
```

Given that all I'm doing in the map function is returning the value * 2 I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot "*use `Prices` as a `Map`*", because `Prices` is *not* a `Map`. The way you have defined it, `Prices` is a different type, not at all the same as a `Map`, but it *contains* an instance of a `Map` inside it.

If this is indeed what you meant, then in order to get the `Map` out of a `Prices` value, you need to pattern-match on it. Like this:

```
let GetSalePrice (Prices theMap) = theMap |> Map.map ...
```

Whoa, what's going on here? How is `Prices theMap` different from `prices: Prices`? Why are we putting the type name in front of the parameter rather than behind it via a colon? Isn't that how types are denoted in F#?

You may have a bit of a confusion because you're using the same name `Prices` for both the type and its constructor. To clear this up, let me redefine your type like this:

```
type PricesType = PricesCtor of Map<string, int>
```

Now the function would look like:

```
let GetSalePrice (PricesCtor theMap) = theMap |> Map.map ...
```

So you see, it's not the type that we're putting in front of the parameter. It's the constructor. And this declaration - `(PricesCtor theMap)` - tells the compiler that we're expecting a parameter of type `PricesType` (because that's where `PricesCtor` belongs), and when we get this parameter, it should be unwrapped, and the map contained within should be named `theMap`.

This whole process is called "pattern matching". Here, we're matching on the constructor `PricesCtor`.

---

Your original function, on the other hand, merely specified the type of the parameter. With my new type definition I might write your original function like this:

```
let GetSalePrice (prices: PricesType) = prices |> Map.map ...
```

Here, we specify that our parameter should have type `PricesType`, but then we're trying to use it as an argument for `Map.map`, which expects a parameter of type `Map<_,_>`. No wonder there is a type mismatch!

---

Pattern matching doesn't have to be in the parameter declaration either. You can pattern-match anywhere in the code. To do that, use the `match` keyword. This is how your function may be written that way:

```
let GetSalePrice prices =
    match prices with
    | PricesCtor theMap -> theMap |> Map.map ...
```

The `match` keyword becomes significant as soon as your type has more than one constructor. For example:

```
type PricesType = PricesAsAMap of Map<string, int> | SinglePrice as int
```

In this case, if you specify the pattern in the parameter declaration:

```
let GetSalePrice (PricesAsAMap theMap) = ...
```

the compiler will warn you that the pattern match is *incomplete*. Indeed, your function knows what to do when given a `SinglePrice` value, but what should it do when given a `ConstantPrice`? You haven't defined that, so the compiler will complain.

This setup is an occasion to use the `match` keyword:

```
let GetSalePrice prices = 
    match prices with
    | PricesAsAMap theMap -> theMap |> Map.map ...
    | SinglePrice p -> "single item", p
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the excellent write up! This makes a lot more sense. I'm coming from a C# background so I was treating the single `of` type as an inheritance. I need to break that!

Comment: Glad I could help